# what character set is the Apple Search API returning the JSON in?

Tags: mysql, special-characters, itunes-search-api

I'm using the [Apple Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html)

and getting a JSON such as the one in [this link](http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=yelp&country=us&entity=software&limit=1)

What character set is the description string in? If I wanted to store this in a mysql table, what character set would mysql have to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to:

> All JSON results are encoded as UTF-8.